# *((uint32_t *) Reading from memory space

Tags: c

I am trying to understand some published code. It starts like this...

```
void *base_address;

int j;
```

And then

```
*((uint32_t *)base_address+ j)=j;
```

If j is a counter, does this mean that if my counter is counting by 1 then the base_address is counting by 4 to allow space for up to 32 bit integers?

If that is correct, how did the programmers get to this syntax?

```
*((uint32_t *)
```

Comment: `(uint32_t *)base_address` casts a pointer-to-void to pointer-to-uint32_t. Then you shift it, then you fetch (dereference) what a resulting pointer points to.

Comment: For *any* pointer (or array) `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is equal to `p[i]`. Now substitute `*((uint32_t *)base_address+ j)` into that.

Comment: In my situation *((uint32_t *)base_address + j) is equal to                 ((uint32_t *)base_address[ j ])..Why the extra * ?

Comment: Still a little confused...Are these two equivalent?                             ((uint32_t *)base_address[ j ]) the same as  uint32_t (*base_address)[ j ].

Comment: the "extra" * is to dereference the pointer.

Comment: Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 7):

If `j` is counting by `1`, `(uint32_t *)base_address+ j` expression is counting by 4, which is `sizeof(uint32_t)`.

The syntax in your post is a version of the code below, except your code is written without an introduction of an additional variable:

```
uint32_t *ptr = (uint32_t *)base_address;
*(ptr+j) = j;
```

or its equivalent

```
uint32_t *ptr = (uint32_t *)base_address;
ptr[j] = j;
```